# "The name does not exist in the current context javascript" + Window.Location

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Using javasciprt function for performing the similar function as Response.Redirect.

```
function redirectToHome(sessionID) {
        window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx") + "?SessionGUID="+ sessionID  %>'}
```

Passing sessionID from codebehind:

```
string sessionId = system.guid.new().tostring();
btnClose.attributes.add("OnClick","javascript:function(redirectToHome("sessionId" ));");
```

Code maybe not exactly the same but i am doing pretty much above.

But at the page rendering its giving error message
"the sessionID does not exist in the current context javascript"
Please suggest another way of doing this.

Comment: from codebehind access the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `redirectToHome` function

```
window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx") + "?SessionGUID="+ sessionID  %>'
```

The entire string is within `<% ... %>`, hence rendered by .NET before being passed down to the server. So `sessionID` there will be assumed to be a .NET variable, and whatever you pass to the javascript function will never be used. (Try "view source" so see what your code really renders like)

You need to either move `sessionID` outside of the .NET block:

```
window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx") %>' + '?SessionGUID=' + sessionID;
```

*or* generate the session id from the .NET block immediately when creating the function:

```
window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx") + "?SessionGUID="+ System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>'
```

If you do decide to pass the session ID through the javascript variable, you have to make note of some additional issues:

Your code will currently print something like (assuming you've fixed the string concatenation issue):

```
 onclick="javascript:function(redirectToHome(e4bd5302-a77c-40f4-9439-6b510bb4cdf3))"
```

This has a set of problems:

- You don't need to specify `javascript:`  in `onClick` as it is already a javascript-specific attribute.
- You shouldn't wrap that code in `function( ... )`
- You're not quoting the string ID

The correct call would look something like this:

```
btnClose.attributes.add("OnClick","redirectToHome('" + sessionId + "');");
```

Note that this could equally well be written as:

```
btnClose.OnClientClick = string.Format("redirectToHome('{0}');", sessionId);
```

which is perhaps more readable.